# How to properly update a line of text

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a basic non static line of text that doesn't reprint itself but `\r` is either not working or I'm doing it wrong; I am a very new person to java so I'm sorry if the answer is really obvious. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextFight {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int MonsterHealth = 10;
        int YourHealth = 15;

        while(true) {

            System.out.println("............");
            System.out.print("\r............");
            System.out.println("|          |");
            System.out.print("\r|          |");
            System.out.println("|  0   0   |");
            System.out.print("\r|  0   0   |");
            System.out.println("| -------  |");
            System.out.print("\r| -------  |");
            System.out.println("............");
            System.out.print("\r............");

            System.out.println(MonsterHealth);
            System.out.print("\r" + MonsterHealth);

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("............");
            System.out.print("\r............");
            System.out.println("|          |");
            System.out.print("\r|          |");
            System.out.println("|  0   0   |");
            System.out.print("\r|  0   0   |");
            System.out.println("| -------  |");
            System.out.print("\r| -------  |");
            System.out.println("............");
            System.out.print("\r............");

            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println(YourHealth);
            System.out.print("\r" + YourHealth);

        }

    }

}
```

What it's doing is this:

```
15............

............|          |

|          ||  0   0   |

|  0   0   || -------  |

| -------  |............

............10

10

............

............|          |

|          ||  0   0   |

|  0   0   || -------  |

| -------  |............

............
15

15............

............|          |

|          ||  0   0   |

|  0   0   || -------  |

| -------  |............

............10
```

Please give me examples of code again I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each piece on a new line, you should use `println` instead of `print`:

```
System.out.println("............");
System.out.println("............");
System.out.println("|          |");
System.out.println("|          |");
System.out.println("|  0   0   |");
...
```

or add a new-line character `"\n"` and use `print`:

```
System.out.print("\n............");
System.out.print("\n............");
...
```

Comment: "Reprint" usually refers to overwriting the line with new content (typically used to animated a spinner or progress bar on console). This is done with using the CR (\r) without a linefeed.